# How to register in Microsoft store to public app for free?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I want create an account in microsoft store to public my Windows Store Apps or Windows Phone Store App in it for free.

thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be within the scope of on-topic questions at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that. The store has certain rules by which you have to abide.

You can read on here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657972.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863494.aspx#account_markets

Note: If you're in any sort of school you can approach Microsoft and ask for a Dreamspark voucher (an ISIC card will do as well).

Comment: thanks but i found a solution to do that and i create a microsoft store account for free without anything!!. thanks